# Issue with an authenicated POST to Rails using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, token, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm looking to POST to a Rails app from curl. I have been able to authenticate and get a 200 response. But when I attempt to POST some data it fails.

My controller code:

```
class TestApiController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate

  def server_reporter
   puts params
  end

   protected
   def authenticate
     authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
       # User.find_by(auth_token: token)
        token == '1234'
     end
   end
end
```

when I run this

`curl -v localhost:3000/test_api/server_reporter  -IH "Authorization: Token token=1234"`

I get

````
Started HEAD "/test_api/server_reporter" for ::1 at 2016-10-10 11:27:19 +0200
Processing by TestApiController#server_reporter as */*
{"controller"=>"test_api", "action"=>"server_reporter"}
  Rendered test_api/server_reporter.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 221ms (Views: 220.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)```
````

when I try

```
curl -v localhost:3000/test_api/server_reporter -X POST  -H "Authorization: Token token=1234"   -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"server": {"name": "Asterix"}}'
```

I get the following in the Rails console.

```
Started POST "/test_api/server_reporter" for ::1 at 2016-10-10 15:59:36 +0200
Processing by TestApiController#server_reporter as */*
  Parameters: {"server"=>{"name"=>"Asterix"}, "test_api"=>{"server"=>{"name"=>"Asterix"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken - ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken:
```

Edit: adding the `curl` response.

```
$ curl -v localhost:3000/test_api/server_reporter -X POST  -H "Authorization: Token token=1234"   -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"server": {"name": "Asterix"}}' 
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /test_api/server_reporter HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
> Accept: */*
> Referer: 
> Authorization: Token token=1234
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 31
> 
* upload completely sent off: 31 out of 31 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Meta-Request-Version: 0.4.0
< X-Request-Id: a13faa8e-20b4-4107-ba5f-1c6fde1f8ce1
< X-Runtime: 0.077414
< Set-Cookie: __profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
< Connection: close
< Server: thin
< 
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /test_api/server_reporter
=======================================================================

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after adding the below line in your top of ApplicationController.

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

**UPDATE**

To protect from forgery, Rails will automatically set authentication token in the parameters when it is called as HTML request. To do that you need add the `csrf_meta_tags` in the application.html.erb like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

If it is an API based application you can add the below line to skip that as it is required only for HTML requests.

```
protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
```

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-protect_against_forgery-3F

Comment: Won't that bypass authentication?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Great, thanks that worked. Just checked and it makes sense now as well.